# creating a RAG status via a select query

Tags: php, mysql

Really looking for help with the next step in my query. I'm not a developer, my boss isn't breathing down my neck nor my jobs not on the line. I'm just a beginner, an ordinary guy, floundering in the mySQL/PHP abyss and looking for some support. I don't have the knowledge or experience to solve my problem and hence I have posted here.

So far I have:

```
SELECT typeName, COUNT(bedID) AS count, pRed, pAmber, pGreen, dRed, dAmber, dGreen, sRed, sAmber, sGreen
FROM bed 
JOIN hotel on hotelID = bedHotelID 
JOIN type ON typeID = bedTypeID' 
WHERE bedStatusID = 'available' AND bedHotelID = 666 
GROUP BY bedTypeID
```

It only brings back 3 rows and it works great. It gives me current totals on available beds by type and the alert levels set for each. Each of the three bed types has three possible status'.. What i'm trying to do is check wether the current availability (count) for a bed type has fallen below one of its three alert levels (red amber green). Ideally, I'd like to put that status  in a virtual column but I'm stuck on this first bit...

Am I going about it in comletely the wrong way?

Should I even be doing this in a mySQL query or should I perhaps use PHP to do this?

Hopefully I'm not missing something embarressingly simple but if I am I'll apologise now rather than suffer the wrath of the forum gods...

UPDATE:
Thanks to David K-J I learnt something about CASE today and if it helps anyone in the future here was my final query allowing different bed types to be given separate rag status

```
SELECT typeName AS bedType, COUNT(bedID) AS count,
WHEN COUNT(bedID) <= pRed   AND bedTypeID = 3 THEN 'red'
WHEN COUNT(bedID) <= pAmber AND bedTypeID = 3 THEN 'amber
WHEN COUNT(bedID) <= dRed   AND bedTypeID = 2 THEN 'red'
WHEN COUNT(bedID) <= dAmber AND bedTypeID = 2 THEN 'amber'
WHEN COUNT(bedID) <= sRed   AND bedTypeID = 1 THEN 'red'
WHEN COUNT(bedID) <= sAmber AND bedTypeID = 1 THEN 'amber'
ELSE 'green'
FROM bed 
JOIN hotel on hotelID = bedHotelID 
JOIN type ON typeID = bedTypeID' 
WHERE bedStatusID = 'available' AND bedHotelID = 666 
GROUP BY bedTypeID
```

Works like a charm...

Comment: I think a CASE statement could be used here. Could you add your output from the query?

Comment: At the moment, you have a rather obvious typo. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Strawberry Typos are a way of life for me but it wasn't that that flumoxed me. It's the sql syntax and my lack of knowledge but thatks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT typeName, COUNT(bedID) AS count,
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(bedID) <= pGreen THEN 'green'
    WHEN COUNT(bedID) <= pAmber THEN 'amber'
    ELSE 'red'
END as rag
FROM bed 
JOIN hotel on hotelID = bedHotelID 
JOIN type ON typeID = bedTypeID
WHERE bedStatusID = 'available' AND bedHotelID = 666 
GROUP BY bedTypeID
```

The rag column will show the appropriate RAG status. You will probably have to adjust it to suit how you've implemented your RAG system.

Comment: I've been using CASE albit a little clumsily but the syntax was killing me. I wouldn't have ended up with what you have suggested and in trying it out it looks like you have solved the dilema that I've struggled with for the past three days. Really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.